# findRecord Rejects with successful network request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am doing a simple find record. Getting an odd error.

```
store.findRecord('icon', id) // id = "UUID-ABC"
  .then((result) => {
    //do stuff
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

This fires off a network request and returns an object similar to [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_object-root). As seen in network dev tools:

```
{
  "icon": {
      "data": "string",
      "id": "UUID-ABC",
      "location": "string"
  }
}
```

Rejects with EmberError:

```
"Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined"
```

But I don't understand what is undefined. The id is most definitely defined, as seen in the network return.

I'm the using standard DS.RESTAdapter. With very little other changes. I use a few other actions that return an array of icons model, and they work fine.No errors are reported.

Comment: What is your serializer?

Comment: `data` is a reserved property on ember data models. Try changing `data` to anything else and see if that fixes things

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/380299cfe95d03f70f3411256827895ef860ce4d/addon/-private/system/store.js#L1083 error is here.  so provide you changes. It we'll be cool to see github link